# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object php mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement for `select query`

```
$product_info = $this->mysqliengine->prepare("select product_id, sku from product limit 10");
        $product_info->execute();
        $res = $product_info->bind_result();
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['sku'].'<br />';
        }
```

But It is showing fatal error as

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object**

Comment: This question has been asked many thousand times before. Some of those duplicates were shown to you while you entered your question title.

Comment: @Pekka웃  Yes I referred previous questions but I could not find my silly mistke

Comment: @EditmeHere well if the only problem left is to debug your code, there is no point in asking for the gazillionth time about php, mysqli or prepared-statement, or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to debug yourself

I hope this will solve

```
$product_info = $this->mysqliengine->prepare("select product_id, sku from product limit 10");
        $product_info->execute();
        $product_info->bind_result($product_id,$sku);

        while($product_info->fetch()) {
            echo $product_id.'<br />';
        }
        $product_info->close();
```